# OpenShift Online v2 deprecation timetable

Tags: openshift

What is going to happen to existing OpenShift Online v2 accounts?

Now that v3 is out, it is marketed as the proper OpenShift, and it's great, but I have an account with OpenShift Online v2 and I would like to know if I'm going to be forced to switch to v3 one day? Is there any timetable for deprecating v2?

All I could find is [this one](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/openshift). It's all about OpenShift Origin and does not shed any light on the future of OpenShift Online (see [comments here](https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/12555150-please-prolong-the-availability-of-openshift-v2-on)).

There is also this [empty stub](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/openshift/online) - not helpful at all :)

Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It would be useful to know what language you are using and what databases etc. Then could provide additional pointers to other material such as blog posts that may have been posted about migrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't announced the timetable yet but yes, you should expect to move to the next generation v3-based platform. If you are looking for some guidance on transitioning your app, you should check out [OpenShift Online Migration Center](https://www.openshift.com/get-started/migrate.html). A proper notice will go out.

Thanks for the pointers to the confusing links, we'll get those cleaned up. Also thanks for using OpenShift.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Today Red Hat has published the End of Life date for Openshift v2: September 30th, 2017.

The press release is here: https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/